# How to remove dotted border around select dropdown

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox

Please see example page at: http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/pure-css-custom-form-elements/

When using FF 24 on Mac focusing on the select box produces this:

[dotted border http://c714091.r91.cf2.rackcdn.com/87cff1afa5bfc0c3df11af964e28b8d5e46649e734.png](http://c714091.r91.cf2.rackcdn.com/87cff1afa5bfc0c3df11af964e28b8d5e46649e734.png)

The background post is found here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/10/26/custom-style-all-your-form-elements-with-pure-css-and-no-javascript/

It doesn't show this in other browsers, how to remove?

Comment: I am not seeing the same results.. Tested in latest version of FF and Chrome. (windows..) Might be a mac - browser related issue.

Comment: Have you tried `outline:none`? Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/Fm7L5/

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers, so far nothing is working to remove the "outline" on Mac 10.9.2 / FF 29.0.1

Answer (score 0):

```
select, option {
   outline: 0;
}
```

Should do the trick. I think the outline is on the option, so you can try to take out the `select` selector (lol) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Read some about [Outline Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) to remove the "borders" in the select box.

> **Solution**

```
option, select {
   outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: @JoshC Not really, that's the only solution and it took me longer to post my answer (Just for the record, I didn't seen your post itill now :)) BTW, there is small different if you notice :)